# How to compute the area of that portion of the conical surface $x^2+y^2=z^2$ which lies between the two planes $z=0$ and $x+2z=3$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, multiple-integral

How to compute the area of that portion of the conical surface $x^2+y^2=z^2$ which lies between the two planes $z=0$ and $x+2z=3$ ? I can't even figure out what the integrand will be ( should it be $\sqrt{z^2-x^2}$ ?
 ) and not even the limits .  Please help . thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In order to calculate the surface of the cone $\mathcal{C}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{C}:x^2+y^2=z^2
> \end{align*}
>   between the planes
>   \begin{align*}
> z=0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
> z=\frac{3-x}{2}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   we consider a parameter representation $\Phi(t,\varphi)$ of $\mathcal{C}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \Phi(t,\varphi)
> =\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}
> =\begin{pmatrix} t\cos \varphi \\ t \sin \varphi\\ t \end{pmatrix}\qquad\qquad
> \begin{matrix}0\leq \varphi \leq 2\pi\\0\leq t \leq \frac{3}{2+\cos\varphi}\end{matrix}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- The apex of the cone is $(0,0,0)$ and at height $z=t$ the cone admits a representation by a circle with radius $t$ and polar coordinates: 
  $(t\cos \varphi,t\sin \varphi)$.
- The limits of the parameter representation $t$ in (2) are due to the planes in (1)
  \begin{align*}
  0&\leq t\leq \frac{3-x}{2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad x=t\cos\varphi
  \end{align*}

> **The  lateral surface $S_{lat}(\mathcal{C})$**
>
> The area $S_{lat}(\mathcal{C})$ of the *lateral surface* of $\mathcal{C}$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> S_{lat}(\mathcal{C})&=\iint_\mathcal{C}\left\|\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \varphi}\times\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t}\right\|dS\\
> &=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{3}{2+\cos\varphi}}
> \left\|\begin{pmatrix}-t\sin\varphi\\t\cos\varphi\\0\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}\cos\varphi\\\sin\varphi\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\|\,dt\,d\varphi\\
> &=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{3}{2+\cos\varphi}}
> \left\|\begin{pmatrix}t\cos\varphi\\t\sin\varphi\\-t\end{pmatrix}\right\|\,dt\,d\varphi\\
> &=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{3}{2+\cos\varphi}}
> t\sqrt{2}\,dt\,d\varphi\\
> &=\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(2+\cos\varphi)^2}
> \,d\varphi\tag{3}\\
> &=2\sqrt{6}\pi
> \end{align*}

The integral (3) was calculated with the help of WolframAlpha.

> **The top surface $S_{top}(\mathcal{C})$**
>
> The area of the top surface $S_{top}(\mathcal{C})$ is the intersection of the cone $\mathcal{C}$ with the plane $z=\frac{3-x}{2}$. Its *projection* on the $xy$-plane is the ellipse $\mathcal{E}:x^2+y^2=\left(\frac{3-x}{2}\right)^2$ and after normalisation we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{E}: \frac{1}{4}(x+1)^2+\frac{1}{3}y^2&=1
> \end{align*}
>   Let $\mathcal{D}$ denote the region within the ellipse $\mathcal{E}$ which has area $A(\mathcal{D})=2\sqrt{3}\pi$.
>
> The area of the intersection of the plane $z=f(x,y)=\frac{3-x}{2}$ with the cone $\mathcal{C}$ is given by
>   \begin{align*}
> S_{top}(\mathcal{C})&=\iint_\mathcal{D}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2+1}dA\\
> &=\iint_\mathcal{D}\sqrt{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(0\right)^2+1}dA\\
> &=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\iint_\mathcal{D}dA\\
> &=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}2\sqrt{3}\pi\\
> &=\sqrt{15}\pi
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> We conclude: The area of the surface of the cone between the planes in (1) is
>   \begin{align*}
> S_{lat}(\mathcal{C})+S_{top}(\mathcal{C})&=(2\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{15})\pi
> \end{align*}

Comment: When you express the ellipse in $x$ and $y$ by eliminating $z,$ aren't you actually projecting the ellipse on the $XY$ plane, thereby foreshortening its major axis?

Comment: @Justpassingby: Many thanks for your hint. You're right of course. Error corrected and presenting now a (hopefully) correct answer. :-)

Comment: @user228169: Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! Best regards,

Answer (score 5):

The slope of the plane $x+2z=3$ is smaller than the slope of the cone, so their intersection curve is an ellipse, drawn with brown in the figure. The plane $z=0$ passes through the apex. Therefore, the region we are interested in is a ''hat''.

The projection of the surface region onto to the $x-y$ co-ordinate plane is another ellipse (the red one).

[image]

Between the two planes we have $0\le z\le \frac{3-x}2$, so the red ellipse is detemined by
$$
x^2+y^2\le\left(\frac{3-x}2\right)^2 \\
\frac{(x+1)^2}4 + \frac{y^2}3 \le 1.
$$
So, the area of the red ellipse is $2\sqrt3\pi$.

The slope of the cone is $1$, so the are of the two areas is $\sqrt2$. Therefore, the area of the conic region is $\sqrt2\cdot 2\sqrt3\pi=2\sqrt6\pi$.

(The question did not involve the area of the brown ellipse; just in order to verify the previous answer, from the slope of the plane  $z=\frac{3-x}2$ it is $\sqrt{1^2+(\frac12)^2}\cdot 2\sqrt3\pi=\sqrt{15}\pi$.)

Comment: Very nice graphic! +1

Comment: From where did you get the image?

Comment: It's a geogebra screenshot.